# no desktop after boot

Tags: linux-mint, panel

I startup my laptop. the mint logo appears, then the mouse pointer, then the screen goes to blank and no desktop appears.

I am using linux mint 17.1 xfce.

using ctrl+alt+f2, shows: "[drm:intel_enable_lvds] ERROR timed out waiting for panel to power on".

There is a login prompt, when I do: ctrl+alt+f1. 
Also, for 1 second, there is a loging prompt after the mint logo appears. After startup, when I close the lid for a half a minute and open it again, the screensaver is activated, I type in my password and then the desktop appears again. I looked in the var/log/syslog, but I don't know what to look for. There is a lot of data in that log file Question: how do you go back/exit after typing ctrl+alt+f1?

how do you solve this? I am a novice with linux.

Answer (score 0):

If xfce does not start with boot you can just login with the command startxfce4.
Else, you can add exec startxfce4 to your .xinitrc in your home directory and simply use startx .

Comment: using startxfce4 gives: server is already running for display 0. as said, at startup login prompt is seen for a second, the mint logo, the mouse pointer. all normal. but then the screen turns gray and a menubar without icons is seen. then the screen goes black.